# exception": "Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation:1052 Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

This method i try

```php
$questions = DB::table('questionbank')
    ->join('questionbank_quizzes', 'questionbank_id.id', '=', 'questionbank.id')
    ->join('quizzes', 'quizzes.id', '=', 'questionbank_quizzes.quize_id')
    ->where('subject_id', '=', $request->subject_id)
    ->get(['id', 'subject_id', 'topic_id', 'question_type', 'question', 'marks', 'difficulty_level', 'status', 'quizzes.title']);
```

and the error is

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous (SQL: select `id`, `subject_id`, `topic_id`, `question_type`, `question`, `marks`, `difficulty_level`, `status`, `quizzes`.`title` from `questionbank` inner join `questionbank_quizzes` on `questionbank_id`.`id` = `questionbank`.`id` inner join `quizzes` on `quizzes`.`id` = `questionbank_quizzes`.`quize_id` where `subject_id` = 78)

I want to return in this format can any suggest what we have to do?
{id: 2665, subject_id: "78", topic_id: "95", question_type: "radio",…}

But in scipt has other method but we have to print same data as above

```php
$subject_id = $request->subject_id;
$subject = Subject::where('id','=',$subject_id)->first();
$topics = $subject
    ->topics()
    ->where('parent_id', '=', '0')
    ->get(['topic_name', 'id']);
$questionbank_id = DB::table('questionbank')
    ->where('subject_id', '=', $request->subject_id)
    ->get(['id']);
// $questionbank_quizzes = $questionbank_id->DB::table('questionbank_quizzes')
//     ->where('questionbank_id', '=', $questionbank_id[]->id)
//     ->get(['quize_id', 'questionbank_id']);
// $quiz_n=quizzesExistTitle()->get(['title']);
$questions = $subject->questions()->get(['id', 'subject_id', 'topic_id', 'question_type', 'question', 'marks', 'difficulty_level', 'status']);
// $questions = DB::table('questionbank')
//    ->join('questionbank_quizzes', 'questionbank_id.id', '=', 'questionbank.id')
//    ->join('quizzes', 'quizzes.id', '=', 'questionbank_quizzes.quize_id')
//    ->where('subject_id', '=', $request->subject_id)
//    ->get(['id', 'subject_id', 'topic_id', 'question_type', 'question', 'marks', 'difficulty_level', 'status']);

return json_encode(array('topics' => $topics, 'questions' => $questions, 'subject' => $subject, 'questionbank_quizzes' => $questionbank_id));
```

I have to show in array `quizzes.title`. I have try:

```php
$questions = DB::table('questionbank')
    ->join('questionbank_quizzes', 'questionbank_id.id', '=', 'questionbank.id')
    ->join('quizzes', 'quizzes.id', '=', 'questionbank_quizzes.quize_id')
    ->where('subject_id', '=', $request->subject_id)
    ->get(['id', 'subject_id', 'topic_id', 'question_type', 'question', 'marks', 'difficulty_level', 'status', 'quizzes.title']);
```

but got above error

Comment: You need to put the table name before the id, because you have multiple id columns in different tables, you can do something like : questionbank.id instead of just id. The field will still be id in the result, it's just so the database know which id field you want.

Comment: We did it but one more question i have can you guide me ?

Comment: Hi @Lk77  $questions = DB::table('questionbank')->join('questionbank_quizzes','questionbank_quizzes.questionbank_id','=','questionbank.id')->join('quizzes','quizzes.id','=','questionbank_quizzes.quize_id')->where('questionbank.subject_id', '=', $request->subject_id)->get(['questionbank.id', 'questionbank.subject_id', 'topic_id', 'question_type', 'question', 'questionbank.marks', 'difficulty_level', 'status','quizzes.title']); I have to apply a condition here if quizzes.title not avialable then show a default value and if have more than one value then show in array like [...,...,...].